# Catia VBA, How to set table autoFit in drawing

Tags: vba, catia

I want to set a table autofit in Catia drawing. But I can't find any command.
I'm looking forward to getting some guidance. Thanks

[[image]]

There is my simple code.

```
Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oView As DrawingView
    Dim oTable As DrawingTables
    
    Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Set oSheets = oDoc.Sheets
    Set oViews = oSheets.ActiveSheet.Views
    Set oView = oViews.ActiveView
    Set oTable = oView.Tables

    For i = 1 To oTable.Count
        'Debug.Print oneTab.Name
        'oTable.Item(i).AnchorPoint = CatTableBottomRight
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the row size and the column size to 0, auto-fit is activated.

```vb
Set oTables = oView.Tables

For i = 1 To oTables.Count
   Set oTable = oTables.Item(i)
   for j = 1 to oTable.NumberOfRows
      oTable.SetRowSize j, 0
   next
   for j = 1 to oTable.NumberOfColumns
      oTable.SetColumnSize j, 0
   next
next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried, it doesn't work with all tables.
And it takes a lot of time to complete.

Comment: What is special on this not working tables? Maybe you accelerate the script by switching the _ComputeMode_ off during _setrowsize_/_setcolumnsize_.

Comment: When i switch the Computer Mode off, runtime is greatly improved.
The table is created with Bill of material. And after the code runs, the first table does not change. I don't know why!